# How are SQLAlchemy transactions validated?

Tags: python, database, validation, transactions, sqlalchemy

Or more general: How can I be sure that the data of a retrieved database row (or better model instance) is valid?

Example (not tested!):

```
class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  Column(String(50))

test_stored = SomeClass(name="me")
db.session.add(test_stored)
db.session.commit()
db.session.remove()  # Let's be sure data is taken from db

test_retrieved = SomeClass.query.first()
assert test_stored == test_retrieved
```

I want to be able to detect the following problems:

- Database stored wrong data
- Database send wrong data
- Communication of database and SQLAlchemy was somehow broken/corrupted
- SQLALchemy initialised instance with wrong data

I **do not** need to detect/avoid malicious scenarios (like man-in-the-middle).

To be honest I'm not really sure if this kind of detection is not already part of SQLAlchemy, used database provider and used transport protocol.   And that there is no need to re-detect such problems on application level again.

So any answers/ideas with or without SQLAlchemy background are welcome.

Comment: Is the normal TCP/IP checksum not enough for your use case?

Comment: Not really, it tells me only that the communication is valid. But not if the database or sqlalchemy has somehow corrupted the data.

Comment: I feel like you're overengineering. Unless you're writing code for use in a satellite or something, it's usually not worth the effort to do this kind of thing. What's your use case?

Comment: It's for a ISO 26262 (and others) compliant script execution in automotive sector. The goal is to proof that no technical corruption has happend until my script adopts the responsibility of correct data handling.